# Recognizing C++ template code patterns

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++17, template-specialization

**Is there a preferred common name for the type of pattern described below?**

---

I was reading through a set of some library source files and after reading though the code I can see what it clearly does. That is not the issue. In fact there really isn't any issue, but the more I start to work with templates and read through these documents; some of the patterns are becoming visually recognizable.

---

The code has this kind of pattern...

```
template<typename T, typename U, 
    bool is_T_signed = integer_traits<T>::is_signed,
    bool is_U_signed = integer_traits<U>::is_signed>
struct foo_impl {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo_impl<T, U, true, true> {
    static T run( U x ) {
        return ( (x <= /*some max value */ ) && 
                 (x >= /*some min value */ ) );
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo_impl<T, U, false, false> {
    static T run( U x ) {
        return x <= /*some max value*/;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo_impl<T, U, true, false> {
    static T run( U x ) {
        if ( sizeof( T ) > sizeof( U ) )
            return 1;
        else
            return x <= U( /*some max value*/ );
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo_impl<T, U, false, true> {
    static T run( U x ) {
        if ( sizeof( T ) >= sizeof( U ) )
            return x >= 0;
        else
            return (x >= 0) && (x <= U( /*some max value*/ ));
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U> inline T foo( U x ) {
    return foo_impl<T, U>::run( x );
}
```

---

Where it is simply straight forward to understand what the code is intended to do.

---

> - An empty class template with `<T,U,bool = default, bool = default>` parameters
> - Specializations of all 4 combinations `[t,t]`, `[f,f]`, `[t,f]`, `[f,t]`.
> - They each return `T` and accept `U` as its member function's param and the function is of a static type.
> - These all have `impl` appended to the end of the struct which refers to the `implementation` that is abstracted away from the `user`.
> - Finally a function template that accepts `<T,U>` params and returns or invokes the struct's internal static method.

---

What I would like to know for better understanding so that when I begin to see and recognize patterns like this more often; I then know what to call them. Is there a preferred common name for this type of pattern? I know that the class or struct is being specialized and invoked in a wrapper function template but this is not what I'm referring to. For example some types of patterns of code are called `SFINAE` or `Tag Dispatching`, etc. ... I know that this is probably something simple that I'm overlooking but don't know what to generally call this type of pattern when I see it. I'm not really concerned about the `implementation` details of the `static methods` themselves for this concerns the actual overall pattern of all of the template specializations that are then being invoked by a function template wrapper that would be available to the user.

---

**EDIT:**

---

*Although I'm still interested in a solid answer for my question above, I have also given thought to the following...*

---

Considering that I've asked a question in this manner: I think it might be something worth while and beneficial towards the community at large. My proposal is this: If you know of any specific well known distinguishable code patterns that you could display their commonly known name(s), show a solid example, give a brief explanation of their common uses, and finally list their strengths and weakness as an answer here. I think that this would make for an excellent reference Q/A in general for everyone to look back at if they ever need to know what any of the different commonly recurring code patterns look like visually. If the pattern names are abbreviated, an acronym etc. it is okay to show that such as `SFINAE` but I think it would also be useful to display its full proper name: `Substitution Failure Is Not An Error` some where within the posted answer. I'm interested in seeing how this post will expand and evolve over time.

Comment: If I had to give names, I'd use [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for different pairs of integer types and [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from function call to avoid explicitly indicating the types (since C++17 there is [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to avoid the extra function if you want). I don't know if there are established names for this or other combinations of features.

Comment: @jdehesa I get what you are saying. It's the idea of seeing similar patterns over time. Many times they are usually grouped together. I know the names, meanings and purposes of a hand full such as SFINAE, RAII, Tag Dispatching, and a few others. Knowing what they visually look like is a different story. A few  years back and I wouldn't have been able to recognize any pattern other than basic classes and basic templates. Recently I'm starting to recognize specific patterns in code when I see them, but don't typically know what to call them. This is where I'm trying expand my knowledge of c++.

Comment: @jdehesa This way; I can be a lot more efficient at detecting them, know what they are, how they work and what their general purposes are used for. To improve this skill set would enhance by abilities to be a more efficient developer, designer, programmer, etc. in general as well as to be able to say; wait... I don't need to write this; it's here, or there etc. and just plug it in and link the connections and use it. Oh it is also improves debugging abilities too.